# Vim - LaTeX. How to conditionally open the PDF viewer?

Tags: vim

I'm currently trying to write my own setup for autocompiling and previewing LaTeX code using Vim and Zathura. This is the code I have currently have in my `tex.vim` file:

```
:map <F6> :w <bar> ! pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %<CR><CR>
:map <F7> :! zathura $(echo % \| sed 's/tex$/pdf/') & disown<CR><CR>
```

This works fine as long as when I compile the code (from Vim) I am in the directory where my tex files are. However, I would like this to work regardless of my position (since I frequently open files from Vim using the `:e` command). How do I fix this?

Also, I would like Zathura to open only if the PDF preview is not already open. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:h filename-modifiers` instead of your `sed` hack, so this should do:

```
nnoremap :<C-u>w <bar> ! pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %:p<CR>
nnoremap :<C-u>! zathura %:p:r.pdf<CR>
```

I have also changed these mappings to use `:nnoremap` which you should prefer anyway.

---

If you want to expand your Vim-fu even further you can check `:h compiler` and `:h compilet-tex` which will handle setting proper `'makeprg'` for you which will allow you to use `:make` to build your TeX files.

Comment: I had to disown zathura because I want to be able to edit my .tex files and view the pdf at the same time, but other than that this worked.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to simply use vimtex (https://github.com/lervag/vimtex)

Mapping: <localleader>lv